# Can't connect to IPSec VPN via D-Link DIR-100 router

Tags: networking, router, cisco-vpn-client, ipsec

I am trying to connect to VPN via Cisco Systems VPN Client with IPSec/UDP transport, but I am getting error:

> Secure VPN Connection terminated locally by the Client. Reason 412:
>   The remote peer is no longer responding

Firewall on Windows and firewall on router are disabled so no ports should be blocked. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why it doesn't work with Cisco Systems VPN Client, but it works with Shrew Soft VPN Client! :)